# text_field_tag and number_to_phone usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textfield

I have an input field where user enter a phone number

```
<%= text_field_tag :mobile_number, '',
```

I need to reformat the phone number using `number_to_phone` how can I add this method to my `text_field_tag`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like

```
text_field_tag :mobile_number, number_to_phone(1234567890)
```

If you already have a default number in mind for the field.